# Python: How to get attribute of attribute of an object with getattr?

Tags: python, object, attributes

How do I evaluate

```
a = myobject.id.number
```

and return None if it myobject is `None`

with built-in `getattr`? Maybe `getattr(myobject, "id.number", None)`?

Comment: Is there any particular use case you have in mind for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
getattr(getattr(myobject, "id", None), "number", None)
```

should work.

Answer (score 7):

This should scale well to any depth:

```
reduce(lambda obj, attr : getattr(obj, attr, None), ("id","num"), myobject)
```

Answer (score 4):

my favorites are

```
from functools import reduce
try:
  a = reduce(getattr, ("id", "number"), myobject)
except AttributeError:
  a = None
```

or

```
from operator import attrgetter
try:
  a = attrgetter('id.number')(myobject)
except AttributeError:
  a = None
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner

```
a = myobject is not None and myobject.id.number or None
```

It doesn't check whether id is None, but that wasn't part of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly over generic solution keeping in view all members:

```
if myobject and myobject.id and myobject.id.number:
    a = myobject.id.number
else:
    a = None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return myobject.id.number if myobject else None
```

Comment: is there a nicer way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function which does it for any level.

```
def Resolve(object, attribute:str):
  """
  Resolve attribute of an object.
  """
  attribute_list = attribute.split(".")
  obj = object
  try:
    for att in attribute_list:
      obj = getattr(obj, att)
  except AttributeError:
    obj = None
    
  return obj
```

To use it you write:

```
a = Resolve(myobject, 'id.number')
```

The code simply splits the string using the the period character and loops through the attributes. If you had another level say `myobject.id.number.another' you would use:

```
a = Resolve(myobject, 'id.number.another')
```